# Access Office365/SharePoint Online search web service unsing ADALiOS

Tags: ios, sharepoint, office365, adal

I'm try to access the Office365 (SharePoint) search service of my tenant, e.g.:
https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/search.asmx
from iOS using the ADALiOS library (https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-iOS).

The samples all seem quite complex, setting up another application, integrating Web API, etc.

In the end, I think I just have to authenticate once, get the token and send it which each request.

Is there any sample available that shows how to do this (seemingly) simple task? 
Or has anybody done this before, maybe even without ADALiOS?

Any hint is appreciated!

Eau

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this one out please?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I use REST web service for the purpose.

The official guide is too obscure. Below you can find samples that cover simple and advanced queries. They will make things clear:

1. full-text and property "title"

   > _https://MYTENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?QueryText='part title:document'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Size,Path,Description,Write,LastModifiedTime,HitHighlightedSummary,ServerRedirectedPreviewURL,FileExtension,UniqueId,DisplayAuthor,UrlZone,Culture'&rowlimit=20&rowsperpage=20
2. full-text and property "author" and "title"

   > _https://MYTENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?QueryText='part title:document author:kapil'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Size,Path,Description,Write,LastModifiedTime,HitHighlightedSummary,ServerRedirectedPreviewURL,FileExtension,UniqueId,DisplayAuthor,UrlZone,Culture'&rowlimit=20&rowsperpage=20
3. full-text and size limitation

   > _https://MYTENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?QueryText='part title:document size>60000'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Size,Path,Description,Write,LastModifiedTime,HitHighlightedSummary,ServerRedirectedPreviewURL,FileExtension,UniqueId,DisplayAuthor,UrlZone,Culture'&rowlimit=20&rowsperpage=20
4. full-text and last modified time

   > _https://MYTENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?QueryText='part title:document LastModifiedTime>2014-08-04T04:09:00.0000000Z'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Size,Path,Description,Write,LastModifiedTime,HitHighlightedSummary,ServerRedirectedPreviewURL,FileExtension,UniqueId,DisplayAuthor,UrlZone,Culture'&rowlimit=20&rowsperpage=20
5. full-text and last modified date

   > _https://MYTENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?QueryText='part title:document LastModifiedTime>2014-08-04'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Size,Path,Description,Write,LastModifiedTime,HitHighlightedSummary,ServerRedirectedPreviewURL,FileExtension,UniqueId,DisplayAuthor,UrlZone,Culture'&rowlimit=20&rowsperpage=20